# If the gradient of two functions are related by a matrix can we say anything about these two functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

Say we have two functions $f, g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which is constant, i.e. not a function of $x$. Say we know that $\nabla f = M \nabla g$, then can we say anything about the relationship between $f$ and $g$?

What about in the case that $M$ is a function of $x$?

I have not been able to discover any relation between $f$ and $g$ in either case, but I feel like there should be something. I know that we can apply the chain rule in the case where we have $\nabla f = \lambda(g(x)) \nabla g$ and $\lambda: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Looking at the constant case, applying the curl to both sides gives $\nabla\times\nabla f = 0 = \nabla\times(M\nabla g)$. So either $g$'s second partial derivatives must satisfy some nontrivial relations, or $M = k I$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: We can also get the same conditions on $f$: $(M\nabla)\times\nabla f = (M\nabla)\times(M\nabla)g = 0$.

Comment: For the dependent-on-$x$ case, all it says is that $\nabla f$ is $0$ whenever $\nabla g$ is $0$. In all other cases, one can always find an $M_x$ which carries the vector $\nabla g(x)$ to the vector $\nabla f(x)$. It is only when you put restrictions on $M$ (such as being constant) that the condition becomes more restrictive.

Comment: I should qualify that I am only referring to the condition that some $M_x$ exists for each $x$, without knowing what that function is. If you are given a specific function $M_x$, then as ever, the condition determines what $f$ can be up to an additive constant.

Comment: If $A \in \mathbb R^{n{\times n}}$ is invertible and $M : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{n{\times}n}$, then $$Af(x) = M(g(x))$$$$A\nabla f(x) = M(g(x))\nabla = \frac{\partial M}{\partial g}(g(x))\nabla g(x)$$$$\nabla f(x) = A^{-1}\frac{\partial M}{\partial g}(g(x))\nabla g(x),$$ where of course $M(g(x))\nabla$ is differentiating $M(g(x))$. If $M(g(x)) = M_0g(x)$, then either $f = g = 0$, $A = M_0 = 0$, or $A$ and $M_0$ each have only one value their entries can take; in the latter two cases clearly $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Correction to the last case: there are $a$ and $m$ such that each entry of $A$ is $a$ or zero and each entry of $M_0$ is $m$ or zero, and the zeroes of $A$ and $M_0$ correspond. I should point out, this is just saying $f(x) = \lambda g(x)$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What is the motivation?

Comment: Why don't you try to make progress in the case where $n=2$?